# Where should cell style code be placed in a MVP architecture?

Tags: excel, vba, oop, mvp

I am using an MVP style pattern in Excel VBA with a userform. My question is, where should I place the code to style a range of cells based off a combo box selection on the userform.

Example: if combo box value equals "Pending" then cells `$A1:$F1` should be yellow. If combo box value equals "Completed" then cell `$A1:$F1` should be green.

Should I place the code in the model, presenter or module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is changing display colors based on cell values.

Visualization code should be presenter 'P'.

It doesn't care how the value is created, just what the final value is.

Comment: thank you! I was leaning towards the presenter class!

Comment: Although, If you intend to use the cell color for further logic then it should be 'View'.
i.e. If cell color is green filter column x. - This would not be pure presentation logic and may be more suitable in view or model logic.

Comment: I see. Further expansion of the logic would be beneficial to be placed in the model as this is seen as the blueprint of the project